# Why the combination of yellow and blue is gray in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In page 1003/1318 TikZ manual there is an example to generate the array of colorful balls as below:

[image]

The ball color in (\x=3, \y=2) is made by combining 50% yellow and 50% blue according to the 2 variable for loop. But instead of green it is gray. Do you know why?
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shading=ball]
\foreach \x / \cola in {0/red,1/green,2/blue,3/yellow}
\foreach \y / \colb in {0/red,1/green,2/blue,3/yellow}
\shade[ball color=\cola!50!\colb] (\x,\y) circle (0.4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ummm, in the screenshot you posted, the "ball" in row 3/column 4 looks disinctly green to me.

Comment: I meant the ball at x=3 and y=2

Comment: yellow is `1 1 0` in rgb, and blue is `0 0 1`, so I would expect gray. Why do you expect green?

Comment: @ Ulrike, because I thought it in painting.

Comment: RGB model is for screen color. It is the light version (yellow = red+green).

Comment: @Aria - The default in-screen color model is the "additive" RGB (red-green-blue) system. You seem to be thinking in terms of the "subtractive" CMYK (cyan-magenta-yellow-black) system.

Comment: Here you mix cola with colb - there is no pepsi involved.

Comment: @hpekristiansen: :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ulrike Fischer and @ Symbol 1 comments:yellow is [1 1 0] in rgb, and blue is [0 0 1] so \cola!50!\colb is [0.5 0.5 0.5] which is gray. The color combination is based on light and not oil color.